# SAS Dehoc Query...Breaking Range Data

Tags: sas

I need your help on developing a de-hoc query for hoc(range) data, below is an example of Shares Outstanding HOC:

```
ID     StartDT       EndDT          SharesOutstanding

ABC         01-Jan-2010   03-Feb-2013     100

ABC         04-Feb-2014   03-Sep-2014     160

XYZ         01-Jan-2011   03-Mar-2012     52

XYZ         04-Mar-2012   09-Aug-2013     108

XYZ         10-Aug-2013   03-Sep-2014     120
```

Now I want to dehoc or break the above range data to per day. Below is the desired output:

```
ID    Date        Shares

ABC  01-Jan-2010  100

ABC  02-Jan-2010  100

ABC  03-Jan-2010  100

ABC  04-Jan-2010  100

ABC  05-Jan-2010  100

.......

ABC  03-Feb-2014  100

ABC  04-Feb-2014  160

....till 03-Sep-2014
```

I am using SAS Code with PROCSQL but that is very time consuming

Need your help on this query at earliest

Thanks
Hitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly easy with a data step and some do-loops.

```
data want(drop = StartDT EndDT i);
  set have;
  format date date9.;
  do i = 0 to (EndDT-StartDT);
    date = StartDT + i;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Do you really want lots of repeated rows, though, or are you just interested in getting the difference of dates?

Comment: Thanks...This was really helpful...saved me lot of time

Comment: Can you please help out on the reverse or opposite of this query --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850738/converting-time-series-data-to-range