# Converting Time Series Data to Range

Tags: sas

I just need the reverse of my Query raised at below link

[SAS Dehoc Query...Breaking Range Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821747/sas-dehoc-query-breaking-range-data/25822147#25822147)

I am having time series data and want to HOC it or want to convert it into range

Please advise

Thanks
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply with a proc SQL group by:

```
proc sql;
    create table output as
    select 
        ID,
        min(Date) as StartDT,
        max(Date) as EndDT,
        Shares as SharesOutStanding
    from input
    group by 
        ID,
        Shares;
quit;
```

Additional details [here.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0tf6s2l1rfv5ln1o04ojc4rotu1.htm)